# Do these two memory register diagrams look correct?

Tags: register, logisim

So to start this off I have used J-K flip flops instead of D flip flops due to the equipment that I'll be using (Logic Tutor LT345 Mk2). The first diagram I am confident is correct but the 2nd diagram being the Parallel to Parallel memory register I am unsure of. Instead of connecting Q to J, I had Q on its own as the output while connecting switched to each J input, looking back at the 2nd diagram I've taken out the input labeled Parallel Data in because I'm confident the bottom four switches will be parallel in and the above outputs being parallel out. I would appreciate anyone's input. Updated image below.

[image: Flip Flops J K]

Comment: Can you in-line the image?

Comment: We discourage broad, open-ended design review questions here on EE.SE, because the answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" on the meta site.

Comment: Expand a bit. Why are you using JK flip-flops?

Comment: In the parallel to parallel register, what is the purpose of 'Parallel data in'?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott I have only just noticed that and as it didnt look right during tests I removed it and now have the bottom 4 switches as my Parallel input.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I have redone my question as it didnt really give any info as you said and expanded on why I did what I did with the diagrams

Comment: From your description both circuits look good to me. What are your requirements that the circuits should confirm to? --- BTW, you can export image files like PNG from circuits in Logisim that look much better. No need to take a picture. ;-)